# Average on chart per legend on PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1TDt.png)
I have table above. i add new calculated column of cost per sqm with a simple cost/area.

i want to make a graph with zone as legend with the average of (total cost per zone / total area per zone) and not an average of the cost per sqm per project. *to show per zone 43.59 and not 46.73*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlnN5.png)

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following Measure here

```
Cost Over Area per Zone = DIVIDE(SUM('table'[cost]),SUM('table'[area]))
```

Then I made clustered bar chart with the new measure in the Xaxis and the legend as the zone.

[image]

(note, I didn't have all the data for zone 4 from your screen shot)